# gxt + Java EE hosted mode

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, gxt

I'm trying to develop a Java EE + gxt application. I have an rpc call which calls a session bean's method.
If I compile the project and run it in the browser, it works fine, but when I use
hosted mode I get an exception like this: (edited for readability)

Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call

...

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null at org.Pecc.server.services.AppServiceImpl.
getUserEmailByName(AppServiceImpl.java:53)

**Line 53** is:

```
return appSessionBeanBean.getUserEmailByName(name);
```

It's like the session bean can't be reached. Note that I have GWT4NB plugin and use it's "GWT hosted mode (**w/o a Java EE server**)" command, but I have glassfish running and the ejb module deployed in it. Shouldn't it be enough to work? If I remember right, I was able to use my ejb module in hosted mode at some point.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I hate to ask this, but are you able to debug and confirm the appSessionBeanBean is indeed not null? And if not, with log statements...

Comment: it is indeed null, that's the problem. :)
but it works completely in compiled mode.

Comment: Did you debug/log the code to see where it's set in compiled mode?

Comment: well, it is set to:
appSessionBeanBean = ($Proxy40) sessionbeanek.AppSessionBeanLocal_14095549

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround by redirecting the hosted mode browser to the module deployed in glassfish. I simply write localhost:8080/EasyTicket-web into the address bar instead of localhost:8888 (jetty's port.). Of course, glassfish has to be started for that to work.

Comment: why don't you just do "Project/Debug"?